# Edit Grub whithout Grub customizer

Tags: grub2

I want to customize my Grub bootloader. I tried Grub Customizer. It is very good but I can't do what I want.
I want to add icons for every option. No problem with normal entries. I delete them, copy their scripts from grub.cfg, add a '(script code)' entry, paste code there and add a class in script (--class favorite_icon_name).
When I want to add a class to a submenu (--class folder), I do the same but submenu doesn't appear there (and also while booting).
I know I can directly edit /boot/grub/grub.cfg, but if I run grub-mkconfig, changes will revert. I don't want to copy and paste grub.cfg everytime!
What can I do? Can I edit grub.cfg and generate files in /etc/grub.d using it? (something like grub-mkconfig but reverse!)
And something else: How can I get rid of 'Removed items' in grub customizer?

Comment: I'm still waiting for an answer...

Comment: See https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MaintenanceFreeCustomGrub2Screen

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, I found the solution myself!
I found that I my custom scrips in the `/etc/grub.d/40_custom`. I wanted to edit them but they were very messy. So I booted to a live Ubuntu usb and copied `grub.d` folder from live Ubuntu to Home folder in main Ubuntu.
After creating a backup from `grub.d` folder, I deleted files in it and copied files from Home folder. Then renamed and deleted some entries using 'Grub Customizer'.
After that, I copied my favorite scripts to `/etc/grub.d/40_custom` file using gedit. Finally, I ran `sudo update-grub`. Now everything is as I wanted!
***If you know another solution, please post it here.*** Thanks!